# Как вывести подменю на странице?

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть только одно меню.
(пример одного из пунктов)

```
Судостроение (страница)
     Танкеры (рубрика)
     Сухогруз (рубрика)
```

Как вывести на странице "Судостроение" в другом месте ее подменю?

Comment: Сайт для Лизы, что ли? Судостроение!

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Спасибо, исправил. Опечатка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо вывести меню ещё раз, используя свой фильтр, чтобы отсечь в нём только `current-menu-item` и те пункты, что под ним. Добавьте такой код в шаблон страницы.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_nav_menu_objects_filter', 10, 2 );

$args = array(
    'menu' => 'Main',
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );

/**
 * Filters the sorted list of menu item objects before generating the menu's HTML.
 *
 * @param array $sorted_menu_items The menu items, sorted by each menu item's menu order.
 * @param stdClass $args An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */

function wp_nav_menu_objects_filter( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
    if ( 'Main' !== $args->menu ) {
        return $sorted_menu_items;
    }

    $items        = array();
    $current_item = null;

    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $item ) {
        if ( $current_item && intval( $item->menu_item_parent ) === $current_item ) {
            $items[] = $item;
            continue;
        }

        if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes, true ) ) {
            $current_item = $item->ID;
            // $items[]      = $item;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Результат работы этого кода можете посмотреть на главной странице моего тестового сайта: http://test.kagg.eu/

Comment: А как вывести только под меню без ссылки на родительскую?

Comment: Я думал, из кода это очевидно ). Закомментировал 1 строчку.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, почему данный код не выводит подменю в родетельской рубрике?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за кусок кода, однако мне он не помог, т.к. у меня есть несколько пунктов в меню и у каждого из него своё подменю (вобщем несколько уровней вложенности) и классы только стандартные (одинаковые у всех, не уникальные). Я переработал его немного и в итоге получил то что выводит все подпункты (любая вложенность) определенного пункта меню. По айдишнику. Если кому понадобится, забирайте...

Например если нужный пункт меню с айдишником 37

```
//Добавим фильтр который оставит только подпункты определенного меню с ID=37
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_nav_menu_objects_filter', 10, 2);

//Вывод отфильтрованного меню
$args = array(
    'menu' => 'Top Menu',
);
wp_nav_menu($args);

/**
 * Filters the sorted list of menu item objects before generating the menu's HTML.
 *
 * @param array $sorted_menu_items The menu items, sorted by each menu item's menu order.
 * @param stdClass $args An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */

// фильтр который оставит только подпункты определенного меню с ID=37
function wp_nav_menu_objects_filter($sorted_menu_items, $args)
{
    if ('Top Menu' !== $args->menu) {
        return $sorted_menu_items;
    }

    $items        = array();
    $parents       = array();
    $parents[]     = 37; //ID пункта нашего меню чьё подменю надо вывести.

    foreach ($sorted_menu_items as $item) {
        if (in_array(intval($item->menu_item_parent), $parents, true)) {
            $items[] = $item;
            $parents[] = $item->ID;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```