# Проблема с вывод подменю в рубриках WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такой пример меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью данного кода я хочу вывести кроме основного меню еще и подменю в другом месте. Когда мы находимся на странице `1`, `1.1`, `1.3` или рубрике `1.2` должно отображаться подменю, тоже самое и с рубрикой `2`.

[Исходный код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890072/193678) был взят из этого ответа.
Я изменил немного структуру и подправил строку, что бы выводить подменю и на вложеных страницах/рубриках.

```
$current_item = ($item->menu_item_parent) ? $item->menu_item_parent : $item->ID;
```

Сейчас проблема в том, что данный код выводит подменю для страниц, но не работает с рубриками. В чем проблема и как ее исправить?

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_nav_menu_objects_filter', 10, 2 );

function wp_nav_menu_objects_filter( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
    if ( 'Main' !== $args->menu ) {
        return $sorted_menu_items;
    }
  $items = array();
  $current_item = null;


  foreach ( $sorted_menu_items  as $item) {
    if ( in_array( 'current_page_item', $item->classes, true ) ) {
      $current_item = ($item->menu_item_parent) ? $item->menu_item_parent : $item->ID;
        continue;
    }
  }

  foreach ( $sorted_menu_items  as $item) {

    if ( $current_item && intval( $item->menu_item_parent ) === intval( $current_item )) {
      $items[] = $item;
      continue;
    }
  }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: К чему эти извращения? В ВП меню собирается в админке как хош.

Comment: @SeVlad, через админку у меня собрано основное меню. Мне нужно выводить подменю.

Comment: В ВП можно создать хоть сотни меню и выводить их где угодно по каким угодно условиям.

Comment: @SeVlad, создать 10+ меню и прописать кучу условий для нужных рубрик, страниц и не забыть про 3 разных языка, как на меня не самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Даже не знаю почему не оптимальный.. Меню по определению "CMS" должно собираться в админке. Но можно управлять не только меню-ми, но и отдельным его пунктами. Есть даже плаги для этого.